# Search for column values in another column and assign a value from the next column from the row found to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas and am trying to populate a column with the values in another column, where another column contains the same value as in a specific column.

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'StringToCheck': ['10T','125T', '',''],
                   'FromNumber' :['','','',''],
                   'ToNumber' : ['','','',''],
                   'CheckStringHere': ['AAA_ER', 'FGGR_DBC', '10T', '125T'],
                   'AssociatedValue1': ['','','56','16'],
                   'AssociatedValue2': ['','','58','24']})
>>> df
  StringToCheck FromNumber ToNumber CheckStringHere AssociatedValue1 AssociatedValue2
0           10T                              AAA_ER                                  
1          125T                            FGGR_DBC                                  
2                                               10T               56               58
3                                              125T               16               24
```

I want to search for each value in `StringToCheck` inside the `CheckStringHere` column, and assign the value from the `AssociatedValue1` on the row found to the `FromNumber` column but on the row where the value in `StringToCheck` is.

I have tried

```
>>> df['FromNumber'] = df[df['CheckStringHere'].isin(df['StringToCheck'])]['AssociatedValue1']
>>> df
  StringToCheck FromNumber ToNumber CheckStringHere AssociatedValue1 AssociatedValue2
0           10T        NaN                   AAA_ER                                  
1          125T        NaN                 FGGR_DBC                                  
2                       56                      10T               56               58
3                       16                     125T               16               24
```

As you see, the values have been added in `FromNumber` column, but on the row where the values from `StringToCheck` were found in `CheckStringHere`, I need to have

```
  StringToCheck FromNumber ToNumber CheckStringHere AssociatedValue1 AssociatedValue2
0           10T        56                    AAA_ER                                  
1          125T        16                  FGGR_DBC                                  
2                                               10T               56               58
3                                              125T               16               24
```

Next, if it is possible to get the values from `AssociatedValue2` to `ToNumber` column simultaneously, it would be a real treat.

P.S.
I am out of ideas what is wrong with this question, I researched and tried a lot of solutions, explained my approach and what did not work. Downvoting questions like this is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a dictionary from columns `['CheckStringHere','AssociatedValue1']` and replace values from `StringToCheck` column:

```
d = dict(df[['CheckStringHere','AssociatedValue1']].to_numpy())
df['FromNumber'] = df['StringToCheck'].replace(d)
#or df['FromNumber'] = df['StringToCheck'].map(d).fillna(df['FromNumber'])
```

---

```
print(df)
  StringToCheck FromNumber ToNumber CheckStringHere AssociatedValue1  \
0           10T         56                   AAA_ER                    
1          125T         16                 FGGR_DBC                    
2                                               10T               56   
3                                              125T               16   

  AssociatedValue2  
0                   
1                   
2               58  
3               24
```

Comment: Clever, so you first create a dictionary out of the `CheckStringHere` and `AssociatedValue1` columns, and then just map/replace values in `StringToCheck`. It seems to work for me. I guess I can use the same technique for the `ToNumber` column.

Comment: @RyszardCzech you are correct, either that, or if you have multiple columns to map you can merge `df.merge(df,left_on='StringToCheck',right_on='CheckStringHere',how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))` and then assign the `_y` suffix of respectve columns to the first :-)