# Regular expression to match all Python definitions in a module

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python module and I want to catch all it's public methods, no private or child methods, for example,

```
def Func1(c, v1=None, v2=None, v3=None):
    def childFunc(c): # I don't want to catch this
```

This is my regular expression:

```
/def ([a-zA-Z]\w+\([\w, =]+\)):/
```

However this also matched the child methods as well and it doesn't work on definitions that spanned multiple lines:

```
def Func2(c, v1=None, v2=None, v3=None, \
v4=None, v5=None):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
(?m)^def ([a-zA-Z]\w*)\(([^()]*)\):
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4xHy7Q/1)

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `def<SPACE>` | 'def ' |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `[a-zA-Z]` | any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' |
| `\w*` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\(` | '(' |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `[^()]*` | any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |
| `\)` | ')' |
| `:` | ':' |

Comment: Thank you this works, the `(?m)` really did the magic for me. I was reading the entire file into a string and was wondering why the regex only catches the first match.

Comment: @reddy You are welcome. Can you please check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136848) please? I am running out of ideas how to improve it, got two downvotes already, no idea why :(

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep out child functions in any other language that uses opening and closing braces would quickly become a nightmare just using regex. But in Python it actually seems doable. Try this:

`^(?:\t| {4})def ([a-zA-Z]\w*\([^:]*\)):`

The `4` represents how many spaces you are using for one indented line, so change it as needed.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k61N63/1)

Comment: Hi, my methods all started at the first position on the line, there is no ident or spaces

Comment: In that case just start it with `^def`

Answer (score 0):

**This does not only catch the function definition (like the other answers) but the whole function.**

```
^def \w+\([^\f\v\r\n]*?\)\:[\s\S]+?^(?![ \t#])
```

explanation;

`^def`  matches the beginning of a line followed by a "def" and a space " ".

`\w+` matches the name of the function.

`\([^\f\v\r\n]*?\)\:` matches a parenthesis containing anything that is not the beginning of a new line (lazy), followed by ":".

`[\s\S]+?` matches absolutely anything (lazy).

`^` matches the beginning of a line.

`(?![ \t#])` requires that the next thing is not a space, tab or beginning of a comment.

Comment: Hi this will match the child and private methods, and it doesn't match multi-lines definitions

Comment: "this will match the child and private methods" No it doesn't.. you are right that it doesn't match if the arguments are on multiple lines, but can be easily modified to do so.